# How to access List object from index as a variable in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

```xml
<c:set var = "arrayIndex" value = "1"/>
```

How do I access an arrayList by the index set by the above statement?
I tried in this way.

```
${arrayList[${arrayIndex}].object}
```

Comment: You can refer this link - http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/how-get-index-value-at-logic-iterate-td3455167.html. By the way your question is missing lot of details which other users would certainly need to look into your issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove encasing `${}` symbol from `${arrayIndex}` to get:

`${arrayList[arrayIndex].object}`

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer @Maurice!